Webform ajax callback not always triggering
I have a Drupal 10 webform and in my module I'm adding an ajax callback ...
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if(strpos($form_id, 'webform_submission_my_form_id') === 0){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'my_module_submit_ajax_submission_callback',
    ];
  }
}

The problem is that it doesn't always get called and I cannot discern a pattern around when and why it does not. I can see in the rendered HTML that the submit button has a data-once="drupal-ajax" attribute:
<input class="webform-button--submit button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit form-item__textfield" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" data-once="drupal-ajax">

And I can see that when that is not present, the callback is not called. I have this form both on its own page (as generated by the webform module) as well as shown on other pages in a block via Twig:
{{ drupal_entity('webform', 'free_price_quote') }}

It behaves the same in either case. I've tried disabling cache altogether and all kinds of things and cannot work it out. Any ideas?
I'll add that ... what I'm ultimately trying to do with the callback is push some data to Google's dataLayer:
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.datalayerWebformEvent = {
    attach(context, settings) {
      $.fn.myFormDataLayerPushLeadSubmit = function(leadData) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'dl_form_submit',
          'form_offer': 'free quote',
          'form_origin': leadData.url,
          'form_location': leadData.location
        });
      };
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);

If there is a suggestion for another way to pull this off that avoids the first issue, that would work as well.
Thanks!

The function definition doesn't need to be in a Drupal behavior, but you need to attach the function somewhere to the DOM in a Drupal behavior so that it can be used. And what is the connection between this client-side javascript and Ajax, which runs server-side and brings its own Drupal behavior in ajax.js? If data-once="drupal-ajax" is missing then this core library didn't run correctly.

@4uk4, the my_module_submit_ajax_submission_callback function calls $response = $form_object->submitAjaxForm($form, $form_state); and adds $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'myFormDataLayerPushLeadSubmit', [$leadData]));

Have you actually created an Ajax command? The InvokeCommand class does not just call some random function, it has to be mapped to a function on the Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype object.   ie. attach your myFormDataLayerPushLeadSubmit function to that object.
